# Consuming platform events on AWS

Tags: platform-event, aws, cometd

Salesforce and Amazon announced earlier this year there is a partnership to allow easier sync between the two tech stacks. I recall in a YouTube video AWS product engineers will be able to consume Salesforce platform events (CometD).

Is anyone familiar with this? And have some instructions or documentation on how his can be done!

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/connecting-aws-and-salesforce-enables-enterprises-to-do-more-with-customer-data walks through this with AWS Lambda function as a CometD client. Corresponding code and docs are under Develop section on [AWS Salesforce Developers](https://aws.amazon.com/featured-partners/Salesforce/Developers) page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use case is addressed in the following [Amazon AppFlow Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/amazon-appflow/make-data-flow-both-ways)

Basically you configure AppFlow to subscribe to Salesforce Platform Events and then you can continue your logic in AWS, for example process the event data with a Lamda function, send it to an S3 bucket, or other AWS handled logic

---

**Edit March 2022**

There's an [Event Bus Relay pilot](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_event_bus_relay_pilot.htm&type=5&language=en_US) which will enable plafform events to be directly passed to Eventbridge (and viceversa) without the need of AppFlow

Comment: I don't see an option for lambda as the destination. Is there any other way?

Comment: @DebuShinobi for that use case you can achieve it passing your Event to Eventbridge where you can subscribe a Lambda function https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/eventbridge/aws-lambda/